# Quickly write roxygen2 itemization code for many items

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a list of column names and short descriptions for the return value of a function.  I'd like itemize these in my R documentation file. A small sample of the column names is

```
c("teamID", "lgID", "G", "AB", "R")
```

Each has a very short description,  but there are a lot of names.  A sample of how I'm writing it now is

```
#' \itemize{
#'   \item{\code{teamID} team}
#'   \item{\code{lgID} league ID}
#'   \item{\code{G} games}
#'   \item{\code{AB} at-bats (plate appearances)}
#'   \item{\code{R} runs}
#' ...
#' }
```

This is repetitive, and time consuming to write.  I've also tried writing it all out with

```
> paste0("\\item{\\code{", c("teamID", "lgID", "G", "AB", "R"), "}", 
         c("team", "league", "games", "at-bats", "runs"))
# [1] "\\item{\\code{teamID}team" "\\item{\\code{lgID}league" 
# [3] "\\item{\\code{G}games"     "\\item{\\code{AB}at-bats" 
# [5] "\\item{\\code{R}runs"
```

but this seems sloppy and the extra backslash is a pain.

Is there a better way to write this so that I can easily insert it into my R file?

Comment: Try this: `cat(sprintf("#'   \\item{\\code{%s} }", c("teamID", "lgID", "G", "AB", "R", "H", "X2B", "X3B", "HR", "SB", "CS", "BB", "SO", "HBP", "SF")), sep = "\n")`

Comment: @flodel - I know it's an old question but would you please post that answer?